# PHP Sanity Check, conditional / comparison

Tags: php, string, comparison, integer

Can someone, for the love of all things natural, please explain why this is happening?

```
$code = 0;
echo $code == 'item_low_stock' ? 'equal' : 'not equal';

// RESULT: "equal"
```

???

A line of code in my app just suddenly stopped working properly, I haven't edited anything around it, changed my php version, anything. When the $code variable contains 0, it is passing as true when I compare it to the string 'item_low_stock'.

I can post the original block of code, but I boiled it down to this comparison and this is what I found.

Halp.

EDIT: PHP version is 5.3.10.

Comment: What you want to use is the equality operator, `===`, which will also ensure that the _types_ being compared are the same. Thus, if `$code` is not 'item_low_stock' _or_ not a string, the comparison works as expected.

Comment: you can check this too https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When one of operands is a number - then php casts another one to a number as well.

So `item_low_stock` string casted to number is `0`, thus it equals to `0`, thus it's `true`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is [converted to a number](http://nz1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) and the comparison performed numerically.

Comment: Wow, amazing.. insane! How have I never come across this in all my years of php developing? Thank you! I guess the change in my app was with a library that hadn't been passing the value of 0 in the $code variable before, prior, the codes had all been strings.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) makes it clear that the two values on either side of `==` are tested *after type juggling*. When cast to an integer, your string becomes `0`. Try the following:

```php
echo (int) 'item_low_stock'; // 0
```

Run it: http://codepad.org/z7LIEumk

If you don't want to engage in type juggling, use `===` or `!==` instead. This tests whether the two values are * identical*, meaning same value and type.

Comment: Worth mentioning the equality operator, so she gets the results she's expecting.